# Getting scipy to accept missing data

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, missing-data, pearson-correlation

I need to include missing data in the scipy pearsonr function. The problem is that if I read it from a file with e.g. 'NA' then I cannot convert it to float so that numpy will accept it. If I read it with numpy then the flexible array type with the 'NA' values cannot be used with 'dropna' or similar. How can I get scipy to accept missing data? I have read about data masks but I don't understand how to use it in the code.

Thanks,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import scipy.stats as sp
import numpy as np

f1=open(sys.argv[1],'r') 

f2=open(sys.argv[2],'r') 

g=open(sys.argv[3],'w')

f1.readline()

otus=[]
metanames=[]
result={}

for i in f1:

    k1=i.split("\t")
    k1[-1]=k1[-1].rstrip("\n")
    otu=k1[0]

    f2.seek(0)

    result[otu]=[]
    f2.readline()

    for j in f2:

        k2=j.split("\t")
        k2[-1]=k2[-1].rstrip("\n")

        if k2[0] not in metanames:
            metanames.append(k2[0])

        x=np.asarray(k1[1:])
        y=np.asarray(k2[1:])

        corr = sp.pearsonr(x, y)

        result[otu].append(str(corr))

g.write("\t"+"\t".join(str(p) for p in metanames)+"\n")

for i in result.keys():

    g.write(i+"\t"+"\t".join(str(p) for p in result[i][0])+"\n")
```

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Comment: which line is throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. A minimal example
would have been helpful. But I guess you get something like the following:

```py
>>> x = np.array([[ 1., 2., 3.], [ 4., 5., 6.], [ 7., 8., 9.]]).astype('object')
>>> x[0,1] = 'NA'
>>> x[2,2] = 'NA'
>>> x
array([[1.0, 'NA', 3.0],
       [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
       [7.0, 8.0, 'NA']], dtype=object)
```

So you have a numpy array of type object because of t he 'NA's.

```py
>>> x.astype('float')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NA'
```

And that's why you can't convert it to float? So all you have
to do is replace the 'NA' with NaN

```py
>>> x[x=='NA'] = np.nan
>>> x
array([[1.0, nan, 3.0],
       [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
       [7.0, 8.0, nan]], dtype=object)
>>> x.astype('float')
array([[ 1., nan,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8., nan]])
```

Comment: Sorry, but no, that's not the problem. Like other examples, you enter the numpy array in the code. I need to read it from a file - so into list or similar which will contain 'NaN' or 'NA'. You cannot convert to float because it has text in it, and if it is not float then you can't convert it to a numpy array to mask or read the 'NaN's. I cannot find any example out there on how to do this from a file. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I avoided using numpy at all and just manually removed 'nan' and corresponding value from both arrays.. by far easier and quicker, shoul dhave thought of it before.

S.

```
f1=open(sys.argv[1],'r')

f2=open(sys.argv[2],'r')

g=open(sys.argv[3],'w')

f1.readline()

otus=[]
metanames=[]
result={}

for i in f1:

    k1=i.split("\t")
    k1[-1]=k1[-1].rstrip("\n")
    otu=k1[0]

    if otu not in otus:
        otus.append(otu)

    f2.seek(0)

    result[otu]=[]
    f2.readline()

    for j in f2:

        k2=j.split("\t")
        k2[-1]=k2[-1].rstrip("\n")

        if k2[0] not in metanames:
            metanames.append(k2[0])


        x=k1[1:]
        y=k2[1:]
        c=-1
        while c< len(x):
            if x[c]=='NaN' or y[c]=='NaN':
                del x[c]
                del y[c]
            else:
                x[c]=float(x[c])
                y[c]=float(y[c])
                c=c+1


        corr = sp.pearsonr(x, y)

        result[otu].append(corr[0])

g.write("\t"+"\t".join(str(p) for p in metanames)+"\n")


for i in result.keys():

    g.write(i)
    for z in result[i]:
        g.write("\t"+str(z))
    g.write("\n")
```